# Why is Dart Uri replacing space with "+"?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using the Urilauncher plugin for flutter to open the mail client. This is my code,

```
final Uri _emailLaunchUri = Uri(
                  scheme: 'mailto',
                  path: 'info@moops.in',
                  queryParameters: {'subject': 'Feedback for Moops'});

await launch(_emailLaunchUri.toString());
```

However, In the email client. The space in the subject gets substituted by "+" symbol. I already tried replacing spaces with %20 and   but then the space gets substituted with these characters. Is there any other special character that I should use to avoid the + symbol and have the spaces instead. Or maybe a way to escape the space.

Comment: Why not just use string literals to build the URL?

Comment: you mean like "mailto: info@moops.in"?

Comment: yeah check this https://flutterrdart.com/dart-strings-literals-and-string-interpolation/

Comment: Alright, but how would I add the subject?

Comment: Try this : `"mailto: info@moops.in?subject=$subject&body=$body"`

Comment: Wow. Thanks. I think you should post this as answer. Might help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the string literals to get past this, I have written a small function bellow to take care of this:

```dart
String getUrl(String scheme, String path, Map<String, String> queryParameters) {
  String url = '$scheme:$path?';

  queryParameters.forEach((String k, String v){
    url += '$k=$v&';
  });

  return url;
}
```

Then you could call it like so:

```dart
await launch(getUrl('mailto', 'info@moops.in', {'subject': 'Feedback for Moops'}));
```

Answer (score 8):

I found a solution to bypass this issue.

```
    Uri _emailLaunchUri = Uri(
         scheme: 'mailto',
         path: 'example@example.com',
         queryParameters: {
         'subject': 'Example Subject & Symbols are allowed!'
         }
    });
              
    launch(
       _emailLaunchUri.toString().replaceAll("+", "%20")
    );
```

The replace all function replaces all + symbols with %20 which stand for space and this solves the problem perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

As a contribution to existing proposed solutions

To understand why this happens, you should know that this is currently an [open issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/43838) on the Dart SDK.

However, the `url_launcher` package has provided a workaround, as stated in their [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher#encoding-urls).

For the sake of convenience, this is the section where the solution is provided:

> URLs must be properly encoded, especially when including spaces or
> other special characters. In general this is handled automatically by
> the *Uri class*.
>
> **However**, for any scheme other than `http` or `https`, you should use
> the `query` parameter and the `encodeQueryParameters` function shown
> below rather than `Uri`'s `queryParameters` constructor argument for
> any query parameters, due to a bug in the way `Uri` encodes query
> parameters. Using `queryParameters` will result in spaces being
> converted to + in many cases.
>
> ````dart
> return params.entries
>       .map((MapEntry<String, String> e) =>
>           '${Uri.encodeComponent(e.key)}=${Uri.encodeComponent(e.value)}')
>       .join('&'); } // ···   final Uri emailLaunchUri = Uri(
>     scheme: 'mailto',
>     path: 'smith@example.com',
>     query: encodeQueryParameters(<String, String>{
>       'subject': 'Example Subject & Symbols are allowed!',
>     }),   );
>
>   launchUrl(emailLaunchUri); ``` 
>
> ...
> ````

Please visit the [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) to constantly have updated information.